# Convert String (varchar) into milliseconds in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have string input in a row ('16-04-2019;16-04-2020;') 
I take the last date like this - `SUBSTRING(dates,-11,10)` - in this example, this will take `'16-04-2020'` , now I want to convert it to milliseconds, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use combination of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and `STR_TO_DATE` functions:

```
SELECT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(dates,-11,10),'%d-%m-%Y'))*1000)
```

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5pmDBwCJYsnzLJ6CPbXH6Q/0)

---

- [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function will convert the date string in **DD-MM-YYYY** format to **YYYY-MM-DD** (MySQL Date format)
- [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function will then convert this Date to Unix time, in seconds. You can multiply this by 1000 to get the timestamp in mil